# Can silver-colored mesh be drawn in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, kinect, mesh

I would like to know how to draw the following meshes in such color in Matlab. [image: Colored mesh] The images are extracted from Microsoft paper on Kinect ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/kinectfusion-real-time-dense-surface-mapping-and-tracking/)). It seems there is no default colormap of these sort. Do I need to create a new colormap?

Comment: There is no silver mesh. That mesh is purely gray, and has light applied to it. Similarly, I assume that the first one has a light reflection depending on the direction the light is reflected to (e.g. upwards light is colored green) . The second one ("silver") should be fairly easy to draw in matlab if you have the mesh.

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri for the thought also on the left one.

Answer (score 0):

The image shown is from figure 1, where they write that the lighting is Phong-shaded renderings (greyscale). This is what you call "silver-colored",  i.e. colormap('gray') combined with reflections.

A quick google search suggests you looking at https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35240-matlab-plot-gallery-change-lighting-to-phong/content/html/Lighting_Phong.html

Comment: I tried using `grayscolormap gray;
    lighting phong;` but it still seems to be not so silver-like. I made a custom colormap to tune it. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data are you working with. Please add details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to make a custom milky colormap.

```
    trisurf(tri, vertex(:, 1), vertex(:, 2), vertex(:, 3), 0, 'edgecolor', 'none');
    axis equal;
    axis vis3d;
    light('Position', [0 0 1], 'Style', 'infinite');
    colormap jet;
    map = [0.83,0.82,0.78 
            1,1,1];
    colormap(map);
    lighting phong;
```

The result goes like this,[image]